# Rigidbody meshes eject each other

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I’m trying to make rose petals falling from a flower by using rigidbody simulation.
The problem is that cause of the proximity of the petals, the rigidbody simulation make them explode instead of making them fall one by one in a natural way…
I can not upload the video, or the screenshot of my physics settings but they are the rigidbody basics one.
If anybody have a solution to avoid the proximity ejection, or an other way to make the falling works i will be very grateful.

(sorry for my english i’m french trying by best:))

Thanks a lot !

Comment: apply the scale of your objects, set the origin to their geometry, in the panel choose Shape > Convex Hull...

Comment: Also check the mass. Lighter objects require higher simulation rates.

Comment: i would try with shape-> mesh and set collision margins to 0, if this does not help you, please provide blend file